# 2D Array size at run time

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

I am getting a matrix (from file.txt) of known size into the same size of 2D array. This code is fine for that.

But now I am really looking for extending this, like getting a matrix of unknown size into a 2D array, i.e. using a dynamically sized 2D array.

Here is the C# code I am modifying.

```
int[,] matrix = new int[3,3]; 
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

#region Reading Matrices From Files
// Matrix 1 Manipulation...............
// Read the file as one string. 
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
//reads all the text of file of given path in a string

foreach (var row in text.Split('\n'))
{
    //outter foreach loop is for setting number of rows equal to number lines by splittin over \n
    j = 0;
    foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        //inner foreach loop is for setting number of columns equal to number chracters by splittin over space

        matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Any help is appreciated....

Comment: So what's the question ?

Comment: Forget using an array explicitly - use `List<List<YourContentType>>` instead. The labour of managing your own arrays is only for when performance problems are proven to exist. Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Comment: But unfortunately I am assigned to do it with array and not the List... @PieterGeerkens

Comment: @MuhammadNomanSajid: If it's homework, say that it's homework. We can better ensure that you learn the necessary concepts if you give us more complete data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is a fixed-sized data structure. It is well used in many languages. Unfortunately once created you may not modify its contents.

That is, how do Lists resize?

List is implemented with arrays, actually. So initially a list holds a fixed number of objects. When you want to add an object that exceeds this capacity, we copy the current array into an array of bigger size, thus increasing the capacity dynamically.

Using this idea, we can actually create your matrix class that automatically resizes from array, rather than List.

I hope the above set your mind thinking about how to create a matrix from arrays! If not, here are more hints:

- keep two integers tracking the capacity of your current arrays. If you want to add an element that exceeds one (say you add an entry to a row but the row is already full), then you want to do a resize operation
- resize operation consists of initialising a new array with bigger (usually double) size, then copy all the values
- don't forget to check that all arrays are of the same size after resize! You might need a loop there